# Export module in react doesn't allow me to import when return is present

Tags: reactjs

In a react project I have the following method I'm exporting.

```
// set options to display
    const showDisplayOptions = (options, resultData) => {

// relative code here removed to save space

      const baseSelection = initialLoadData();
      const filteredData = filterBaseData(baseSelection, resultData);

      return filteredData.map(fltData => {

      })

    }

 exports.showDisplayOptions = showDisplayOptions;
```

Then in a react functional component I import it like so:

```
import { showDisplayOptions } from '../helpers/Options/showDisplay';
```

Bada bing bada boom, it works.  However when I add this to the showDisplayOptions:

```
 return filteredData.map(fltData => {
           let individualOption = [];

           return (
             <span className="select-wrapper-size">

             </span>
           )
  })
```

I then get the error:

```
Attempted import error: 'showDisplayOptions' is not exported from '../helpers/Options/showDisplay'.
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing removing `exports.showDisplayOptions = showDisplayOptions`;

I changed it to an export of the const

```
export const showDisplayOptions = (options, resultData) => {}
```